# How do I use a .png image as div backround?

Tags: tailwind-css

Have a look at my current web page, developed using tailwindcss page below:

[image: Background not yet there]

What now I want to achieve is to have a .PNG background instead of that blank green background in the center.

I am new to Tailwind, so I used to simply set a `background: url(..)` in a css file for particular div class. Looking at TailwindCSS documentation [here about backround-image](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image),I can't see similar functionalities there.

Below is snippet of my code for that particular div:

```
<!--        Content: background image url should be in this div, right?-->
    <div class="flex-1 pt-2 text-2xl font-bold mt-2 mb-2 bg-green-50 rounded-br-3xl">
        <div>
<!--Search field -->
            <div class="w-full">
                <form class="rounded">
                    <div class="px-5">
                        <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Ask me anything (Press CTRL+K to focus)")>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- content -->   
            <div class="px-5 pt-8">Course content here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own background images by editing the theme.backgroundImage section of your tailwind.config.js file:

// tailwind.config.js

```
  module.exports = {
    theme: {
      extend: {
        backgroundImage: theme => ({

         'hero-pattern': "url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')",

         'footer-texture': "url('/img/footer-texture.png')",
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

so hero-pattern will become bg-hero-pattern for example.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Tailwind 3 is out, you can use one-off background images like this, without having to use inline styles or extend tailwind:

```html
<div class="bg-[url('/img/background.png')]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

You can learn more about using arbitrary values in Tailwind 3 in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values).